# What is the difference between red and yellow springs?

Tags: sonic-generations

In Sonic Generations, you can find two types of springs through the Classic levels: red and yellow. Is there any difference between the two kinds of springs, or is it only to confuse innocent gamers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Red springs propel you forward with more force than yellow springs do.

The [Sonic Wikia notes](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Spring):

> Red ones propel Sonic to a higher elevation, while yellow ones only send Sonic a medium to low distance.

It's been this way as far back as I can remember.

Comment: Since the very first game, according to the referenced page.